# Как можно запретить массовое выделение мышкой в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день.Почти неделю назад задавался вопросом о запрете массового выделения мышкой в DataGridView.То есть что бы массовое выделение было доступно только с клавишами Alt и Control.Вопрос до сих пор актуальный.